# İts about not dublicating characters in string in python

Tags: python-3.x

```
def removeDuplicates(x):
    for i in x:
        for j in x:
            if i!=j:
                return j
            else:
                return x
```

print(removeDuplicates("greeeetinngs"))

question:
a function that removes duplicate characters from a string . could yo help me please.
the output greeeetinngs
but output should be gretings. So, my output is wrong could you explain.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

def removeDuplicates(x):
    return re.sub('(.)\\1+', '\\1', x)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, make an empty array, and then loop through the character in the string, if the character is not in the array, add it, and skip if not.
this code snippet should do the trick.

```
def removeDuplicates(x):
    unique = []
    for char in x:
        if char not in unique : 
            unique.append(char)
    return ''.join(unique)
```